# How to select minDate of one datepicker to user selected date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Here I have two datepickers, what I need to do is set the minDate of second one to the user selected value of first one.
My code looks like below

```
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#fromDatePicker").datepicker({
                    minDate : 1,
                });

            });
        </script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#toDatePicker").datepicker({
                    minDate : 2//I need datepicker 1's selected date here
                });
            });
        </script>
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set min-date of *toDatePicker* in [**onSelect**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) event of *fromDatePicker*

> Called when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.

Use

```
$('#fromDatePicker').datepicker({
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $('#toDatePicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
      }
});
```

Comment: How to add one date to selectedDate?

Comment: @MaDu_LK, `How to add one date to selectedDate?` What do you mean?

Comment: I dont want to allow the toDate equals to fromDate. The minimum toDate is actually fromDate+1

Comment: @MaDu_LK, Try with `$('#toDatePicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate()+1));`